# Null stackTrace in com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere

This issue is in a Spring MVC application deployed on Websphere 6.1. When I trying to access a URL that doesn't exist within the application, I'm getting a 404 error. I have an error Controller class that would log all exception and redirect to the error page. The Throwable instance is retrieved from the request in this Controller and this is an instance of com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport. I find that the stacktrace elements as null when I try to access through the getStackTrace() method resulting in a NullPointerException in the logback API class during logging. As a result, the screen is not redirected to the error page and the entire stacktrace is displayed on the screen. Its working fine for other exceptions except the 404 error.

I noticed that the printStackTrace is not overridden in the WebAppErrorReport and am using it to get the stacktrace written to a String for logging.

However, I'm not quite happy with this solution and would like to know if there's any other better way out. Also, I'm curious as to why the stacktrace is null for this error alone?